# Get the all field fromone documents Elasticsearch java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to get all the fields from one document which is have lowest price. Using min i can only get particular price. How should i retrieve in all the fields of one document.

I have written this code which retrieves min price

```
AggregationBuilder aggregation = AggregationBuilders.nested("nestedAgg").path("carSpecPojo")
            .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.min("carSpecAgg").field("carSpecPojo.price"));
    SearchQuery searchQuery = (SearchQuery) new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .addAggregation(aggregation).build(); 
    Aggregations aggregations = elasticsearchTemplate.query(searchQuery, new ResultsExtractor<Aggregations>() {
        @Override
        public Aggregations extract(SearchResponse response) {
            return response.getAggregations();
        }});
    Nested nest = aggregations.get("nestedAgg");
    Min min = nest.getAggregations().get("carSpecAgg");
```

And my elastic document will be like this

```
 "brand_name": "maruti",
           "model": "i20",
           "year": "2015",
           "carSpecPojo": {
              "engine_power": "400hp",
              "price": 9000000,
              "transmission_type": "auto",
              "airbag": "yes",
              "abs": 1,
              "max_speed": "170kmp",
              "color": "black",
              "fuel": "petrol",
              "mileage": 5,
              "door": 4,
              "seat_capacity": 4
           }
        }
```

When i will get min price XXXXXXX, i need all the fields in this document

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's not possible with the `min` aggregation. What you can do is to use `top_hits` aggregation with size = 1 and sort by `carSpecPojo.price` in descending mode.

Comment: i have 10000 records in my elasticDB , i need all the details, which is the   lowest car. How i will use _top_hits_ aggregation? guide me

Comment: Why not simply one query (without aggregations) with a nested sort (asc) on the `carSpecPojo.price` field?

Comment: when i nest 'carSpecPojo.price' field, am getting more than one filed count then how can i will get first whole json?